# Replacing letters in string w/values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I'm working on an encryption project in python. I've created a dictionary, with the alphabet as keys and randomized letters as values. It is encoded it now, but I would like each letter to be replaced with a unique letter, its pair. Any advice?

```
message = "it is time to code"

my_dictionary ={'a': 'e', 'b': 'f', 'c': 'a', 'd': 'z', 'e': 'r', 'f': 'w',
           'g': 'b', 'h': 'y', 'i': 'l', 'j': 'd', 'k': 'h', 'l': 'c', 
           'm': 't', 'n': 'x', 'o': 's', 'p': 't', 'q': 'o', 'r': 'u', 
           's': 'n', 't': 'j', 'u' : 'k', 'v': 'p', 'w': 'i', 'x': 'g', 'y': 'm', 'z': 'q'}

def create_cypher(message,my_dictionary):

  coded_message = message 

  for char in message:

      if char in my_dictionary:

          coded_message = coded_message.replace(char, my_dictionary[char]) 

  return coded_message  

output: 'lj ln jljr js aszr'
```

Comment: Is there a problem you are having? Seems to work fine. Perhaps you are after [code review?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `str.translate` to replace multiple values at once:

in order to do so you first need to make a translating table with

```
my_dictionary = {'a': 'e', 'b': 'f', 'c': 'a', 'd': 'z', 'e': 'r', 'f': 'w',
       'g': 'b', 'h': 'y', 'i': 'l', 'j': 'd', 'k': 'h', 'l': 'c', 
       'm': 't', 'n': 'x', 'o': 's', 'p': 't', 'q': 'o', 'r': 'u', 
       's': 'n', 't': 'j', 'u' : 'k', 'v': 'p', 'w': 'i', 'x': 'g', 'y': 'm', 'z': 'q'}

trans_table = str.maketrans(mydictionary)
```

then you can use the table to translate a string

```
'hello'.translate(trans_table)
```

output: 'yrccs'

```
"it is time to code".translate(trans_table)
```

output: 'lj ln jltr js aszr'

```
'aaee'.translate(trans_table)
```

output: 'eerr'

with your code 'aaee' returns 'rrrr', because you are translating characters that were already translated

Answer (score 0):

You could also apply a **Ceaser Algorithm**

More formally, Caesar’s algorithm (i.e., cipher) encrypts messages by “rotating” each letter by *k* positions. More formally, if *p* is some plaintext (i.e., an unencrypted message), *p<sub>i</sub>* is the *i*<sup>th</sup> character in *p*, and *k* is a secret key (i.e., a non-negative integer), then each letter, ci, in the ciphertext, c, is computed as

```
ci = (pi + k) % 26
```

wherein `% 26` here means “remainder when dividing by 26.” This formula perhaps makes the cipher seem more complicated than it is, but it’s really just a concise way of expressing the algorithm precisely. Indeed, for the sake of discussion, think of A (or a) as 0, B (or b) as 1, …, H (or h) as 7, I (or i) as 8, …, and Z (or z) as 25. Suppose that Caesar just wants to say Hi to someone confidentially using, this time, a key, k, of 3. And so his plaintext, p, is Hi, in which case his plaintext’s first character, p0, is H (aka 7), and his plaintext’s second character, p1, is i (aka 8). His ciphertext’s first character, c0, is thus K, and his ciphertext’s second character, c1, is thus L.

[More information available here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Comment: thank you! yes, i did end up switching to a ceasar cipher.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a randomizer function to create a "key" and that function basically randomizes the dicionary with letters and after that u could replace the items by it's index instead of its character